# oracle DELETE records while MERGE

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I MERGE records from `newtest` to `test`.

```
merge into test t
using newtest nt
on (t.id = nt.id)
when matched then
  update
     set t.name = nt.name
when not matched then
  insert (id, name)values (nt.id, nt.name);
```

Those records in `newtest` which are fit for `on` conditions need be deleted.

Though i could do it with a `delete` SQL, but i want to know can it be done in that MERGE sentence?

Comment: It can't be done. MERGE can modify only the table listed after `MERGE INTO` clause, but not after `USING` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kordiko clarified, you cannot delete from another table using the MERGE statement. You can accomplish the delete in a separate statement as below:

```
DELETE FROM newtest nt
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM test t where t.id = nt.id);
```